# Using PowerShell to Assign numbers from a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting

I like to think of myself as an amateur / novice at PowerShell.  I'm working on a PowerShell tool to help me assign numbers easier based on the number given off of a spreadsheet. I'm having a hard time trying to find the Assigned numbers to display them to the user. I was trying to avoid using ImportExcel if possible. and just work out of PowerShell through text-based menus for now.

This is kind of what im looking at, just would like it to be easily found while im trying to assign a number for a user based on their location.

So the ide would go something like, I want to assign a number to a user:[image: Step 1 - Assign the number]

I would enter their Details:
[image: Step 2 - Setting the user up]
Then where im being prompted for a user's number it would give me another submenu to either input it manually or I would select the location that I want to assign them a number from. (this part i can handle)

Now for the sake of simplicity Im just using 2 places that I whipped up a couple of quick spreadsheets for.

Sheet1 - Dallas:
[image: Sheet1 -Dallas]

Sheet2 - Chicago:[image: Sheet2 -Chicago]

So I have the basics to opening the sheet

```
Call to create a new comObject to call excel (launching Excel Application in the background)
$ExcelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelObj.Visible=$false
$ExcelObj.DisplayAlerts=$false

#Directory We will be working on, contating the File we want to work on
$ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open('C:\Scripts\TeamsNumbersTest.xlsx')

#Target the sheet to work on Dallas would be a variable based on what they chose, no biggie
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Sheets.Item("Dallas")

#This is the part that I'm confusing myself on. I feel like i need to do a for loop and save the ones I find in an array? something like:
foreach($Names in $ExcelWorkSheet){
   $ExcelWorkSheet | Where-Object Names -eq 'Available'
   $Found = $ExcelWorkSheet.Columns.Name.DID
} 

#Save and clean up the mess
$ExcelWorkBook.Save()
$ExcelWorkBook.Close($true)
$ExcelObj.Quit(
```

I would like to have an output that would be a selectable menu.
Was hoping to make the output look something like:

| Selection | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12341236560 |
| 2 | 12341236561 |

Prompt the user like: Please select an available number from the list above:

then would right that information back to the excel spreadsheet changing the available number to a username, email address etc., or reverse if I unassign from a user change it back to available adding old username to the Notes. So it would look something like:

| Name | UserPrincipaleName | Number | Plan | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Available |  | 12341236561 | National | Was Bob Hope |
| DallasConfrenceRoom | DallasConfrenceRoom@fictionalplace.com | 12341236566 | National |  |
| New Guy | NewGuy@fictionalplace.com | 12341236567 | International | Makes Long distance Calls over seas |

Then would save it.

My only question I have is if I have that spreadsheet set with Conditional formatting to highlight cells that have available numbers (for ease upper management to look at) would that be affected?

Thanks in advance!

So Im still working this issue... decided to play with importexcel to see if it would make a difference and im able to sort out my available numbers using:

```
try{
    $File = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $WorkingFile
    $Sheets = $File.Workbook.WorkSheets[$selection]
    
    $ExportObjects=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $AvailableObjects=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

    foreach($Sheet in $Sheets){
        $Data = Import-Excel -ExcelPackage $File -WorksheetName $Sheet
        foreach($Row in $Data){
            if($ExportObjects | Where-Object name -eq $row.name){
                Write-host "duplicate found"
                $Entry = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                Add-Member -InputObject $Entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $row.Name
                Add-Member -InputObject $Entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UserPrincipalName" -Value $row.UserPrincipalName
                Add-Member -InputObject $Entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DID" -Value $row.DID
                Add-Member -InputObject $Entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CallingPlan" -Value $row.CallingPlan
                Add-Member -InputObject $Entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Notes" -Value $row.Notes
                $AvailableObjects.add($Entry)
            }
            else{
                $Entry = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                Add-Member -InputObject $Entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $row.Name
                Add-Member -InputObject $Entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UserPrincipalName" -Value $row.UserPrincipalName
                Add-Member -InputObject $Entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DID" -Value $row.DID
                Add-Member -InputObject $Entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CallingPlan" -Value $row.CallingPlan
                Add-Member -InputObject $Entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Notes" -Value $row.Notes
                $ExportObjects.add($Entry)
            }
        }
    }
        return $AvailableObjects

}

catch
{
    write-host "Failed"
}
```

No i just need to figure out how to save the row that they are on, so i can go back and edit the sheets.

Comment: When you run your code, are the cells that have Conditional formatting affected?

Comment: still trying to figure that part out. I need to get it to read / write the cells first

Comment: Are you actually an `armature`? :-) https://www.dictionary.com/browse/armature

Comment: I guess in a way you could say I am an armature. I'm like the outer layer of my family, made to keep them safe. but you know I meant amateur. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/amateur